# Quick CSS font query

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

Can anyone tell me why the font in the "NEWS" section of my homepage (the row of three images halfway down http://www.sehkelly.com starting with "Open and shut case") is heavier than the rest of the page?

The font is not bold; it is just heavier.

And seemingly only in Google Chrome.

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: thats pretty odd, you also have a console error its not loading bundle.js.php just a heads up

Comment: It looks fine to me. The bigger the font the bolder it gets. Unless you mean something different.

Comment: Not all Browsers render fonts the same way.

Comment: what browser is the font rendering odd in ?

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the `font-family` rule that's applied to your body it fixes the problem from my testing.

maybe you could define those font's in a less global way?